# failing data insertion after $model->validate() in yii

Tags: php, yii

i am using $model->validate() in yii.. all validations passed but $model->save() doesn't work. What can i do to solve this issue? thanks in advance.

here is my controller:

```
$model = new BaseSysRegistration();
$model->attributes = $_POST['BaseSysRegistration'];
$model->of_passport_number = $_POST['of_passport_number'];
$model->password2 = $_POST['BaseSysRegistration']['password'];
$model->email_addr = $_POST['BaseSysRegistration']['email_addr'];
$model->security_question_1_id = $_POST['BaseSysRegistration']['security_question_1_id'];
$model->security_question_1_answer = $_POST['BaseSysRegistration']['security_question_1_answer'];

if($model->validate()){
        $model->save();
}
```

Comment: Are u getting any error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the validation pass then you don't need to validate the data again, so you can indicate to the `save` method to not `validate` data again

```
if($model->validate()){
    $model->save(false);//see the false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check why the model isn't being saved by using `print_r` on the `getErrors()` method.

```
if ($model->validate()) {
    if (!$model->save()) {
        print_r($model->getErrors());   
    } 
}
```

That should help you to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you alter your one of models properties in beforeValidate() , then you should turn it back to its previous state, try having a temporary property and store the unchanged(original) property into that, and then grab it in afterValidate() , this way you still have the original value.

or like the other guys said, just don't validate in save

```
 $model->save(false); //false : don't validate
```

Answer (score 0):

To execute `$model->save()` you should set the modal data as needed you can validate the data by $model->validate() then try to save

```
if ($model->validate()) {
    if (!$model->save()) {
        print_r($model->getErrors());   
    } 
}
```